# how to change the textview data

Tags: android, listview, textwatcher

i have create an application in which the in my adapter class i set the arraylist in textview..,but on search i want to add another list that have filtered data that user search with the textwatcher in the textview.As my adapter is having whole contact list,i want to replace it with new list that is created with the help of textwatcher.
**MainAactivity**

```
  case R.id.action_search:

                    searchText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            s=searchText.getText().toString();
                            ma.getFilter().filter(s);

                        }
                    });


                    break;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
```

**MyAdapter**

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            tv.setText(name1.get(position));
            tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));



            cb.setTag(position);

            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), String.valueOf(name1.size()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return vi;

        }
```

**getfilter()**

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            public void publishResults(CharSequence s, FilterResults results) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), String.valueOf(name1.size()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                arrayListNames = (List<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence s) {
                search=true;
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++) {

                    String dataNames = name1.get(i).toString();
                    if (dataNames.toLowerCase().trim().startsWith(s.toString()))  {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        FilteredArrayNames.add(name1.get(i));
                    }
                }

                results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrayNames;


                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, what? Please simplify your question and don't paste 2000 lines of code noone is gonna read that. Show us what you tried.

Comment: @ V M I m developing app where there is list and above edit text,the moment i will type something in editText i should get the result matching for the typed word.bt i cant get the result,Plz tell where am i making mistake

Comment: @Himani check my getFilter() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mylistviewtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listview;
    private EditText edittext;
    private List<ProfileBean> list; 
    private SearchableAdapter adapter ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        edittext  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        list = new ArrayList<ProfileBean>();

        list.add(new ProfileBean("AAA", "AA", "123"));
        list.add(new ProfileBean("AAB", "AB", "100"));
        list.add(new ProfileBean("AAC", "BC", "101"));
        list.add(new ProfileBean("AAD", "DC", "154"));
        list.add(new ProfileBean("BBB", "DF", "22"));
        list.add(new ProfileBean("BBA", "AD", "22"));
        list.add(new ProfileBean("BBD", "FD", "44"));
        list.add(new ProfileBean("BAT", "AD", "44"));
        list.add(new ProfileBean("BBD", "FF", "75"));
        list.add(new ProfileBean("BAD", "AA", "88"));


        adapter = new SearchableAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ProfileBean bean = (ProfileBean) arg1.getTag();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bean.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**ProfileBean**

```
package com.example.mylistviewtest;

public class ProfileBean {
    private String name;
    private String lname;
    private String no;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    public String getNo() {
        return no;
    }
    public void setNo(String no) {
        this.no = no;
    }
    public ProfileBean(String name, String lname, String no) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.no = no;
    }



}
```

**SearchableAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.mylistviewtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

// The standard text view adapter only seems to search from the beginning of whole words
// so we've had to write this whole class to make it possible to search
// for parts of the arbitrary string we want
public class SearchableAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<ProfileBean>originalData = null;
private List<ProfileBean>filteredData = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public SearchableAdapter(Context context, List<ProfileBean> data) {
    this.filteredData = data ;
    this.originalData = data ;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
    // to findViewById() on each row.
    ViewHolder holder;

    // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
    // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
    // by ListView is null.
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
        // we want to bind data to.
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.lname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lname);
        holder.no = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.no);

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.

        convertView.setTag(R.layout.list_item,holder);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
        // and the ImageView.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.layout.list_item);
    }

    // If weren't re-ordering this you could rely on what you set last time

    ProfileBean bean = filteredData.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(bean.getName());
    holder.lname.setText(bean.getLname());
    holder.no.setText(bean.getNo());
    convertView.setTag(bean);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView lname;
    TextView no;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<ProfileBean> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<ProfileBean> nlist = new ArrayList<ProfileBean>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            ProfileBean bean =  list.get(i);
            filterableString = bean.getName();
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(bean);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<ProfileBean>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: FilteredArrayNames.add(name1.get(i)); in this what is i..??

Comment: check i have updated code FilteredArrayNames.add(p);

Comment: @ Kanaiya Bhanushali tnx but it didn't help me..,actually i knw problem is with my getview() in MyAdapter,in which i hardcode textviews with name1 arraylist,but i dont knw how change the arraylist name1 with FIlteredArrayNames

Comment: there is no error m getting my prevoiusly defined arraylist not the filtered one

Comment: problem is with this   
            tv.setText(name1.get(position));
            tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));
in which name1 and phone1 is the arraylist that have all the contact names ans number...but after filter new arraylist is created FIlteredArrayNames,now i dont knw how to set this arraylist in textview to get the result

Comment: which adapter r u using ?

Comment: custom adapter that i post above as MyAdapter

Comment: i konw but r u extending which type of adeptor

Comment: i am extending BaseAdapter